# Is JMeter KB/sec input or output?

Tags: jmeter

During performance test, KB/sec shows the average bandwidth used per request: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html

Does this value include both input/download and output/upload Bytes or just input/download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only includes the input/download.

But if you want the upload then you can use :

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/BytesThroughput/

Note graph in documentation is not up to date as in fact it reports both send and received bytes.

See this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/